# Is there anyway to encode with encoding type in C++

Tags: c++, encoding

I'm new to C++ and what I'm facing right now is that I have to encode the input string from the user from these encoding to hex. Is there any relevant library or function in C++ that can have the same output as Charset in Java? I have already implemented this in Java.

I need to support the following encodings:

- **US-ASCII** Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin block of the Unicode character set
- **ISO-8859-1** ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
- **UTF-8** Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
- **UTF-16BE** Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format,big-endian byte order
- **UTF-16LE** Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format,little-endian byte order
- **UTF-16** Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order
  identified by an optional byte-order mark

In Java I simply used

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName(Enum.valueOf(opentestsystem.otf.model.types.Encodings.class,
            encoding.name()).toString());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us. And lastly, pick *one* language and don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits -- if I understood the question right ?

Comment: @ChefGladiator I don't know yet but if you know how to use Charset in Java probably you can help me with that. I have researched a lot but don't seem any relevant lib or function that is the same  as Charset in Java

Comment: It is best if you post your short but complete C++ code, showing what seems to be the problem..

Comment: @ChefGladiator because I'm at beginning so I don't have any code in C++ yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`libiconv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Comment: VSCode said that cannot import #include <iconv.h>. Can you help me with this??

Comment: You need to install `libiconv` first, then tell your compiler where to find the headers (include path) and link to the library (linker flags `-liconv`). Read the manual or search StackOverflow to find out how to do that.

Comment: @Botje we do not know what platform and compiler OP uses.